# How to formulate with a tensor multiplication method $2\otimes 2\otimes 2$ in $SU(2)$ group?

Tags: nuclear-physics, tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory, isospin-symmetry

In $SU(2)$ we can write $2\otimes 2=3\oplus 1$ or 
\begin{equation}
q_iq^j=\left(q_iq^j-\frac{1}{2}\delta^i_jq^kq_k\right)+\frac{1}{2}\delta^i_jq^kq_k,
\end{equation}
where $q_i$ is a $SU(2)$ doublet, the first term of the rhs transforms as a triplet and the second one as a singlet.

With this representation, we can express triplets depending on the $q_i$ content. For instance, if $q=\left(u\;d\right)^T$, then a pion triplet is obtained.

I'm looking for a $SU(2)$ quartet that is supposed to be obtained from $2\otimes 2\otimes 2=2\oplus 2\oplus 4$. I mean, I would like to find a tensor equation like the one written above.

Comment: Add three spin doublets.

Comment: I think you fully symmetrize the indices: $T_{ijk}\equiv q_{\{ijk\}}\propto q_{ijk} + q_{jki}+ ...$ and subtract the trace $v_i \equiv T_{iij} = T_{iji} =T_{jii}$ multiple by a delta function (and symmetrized): $v_i\delta_{jk} +v_j\delta_{ki}+...$ with a weight. The weight is 3/5 for SO(3), but I don't know what it is for SU(2), so I'm sticking to comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might profit from the [*Introduction to unitary symmetry* book by P Carruthers](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_unitary_symmetry.html?id=t33soAEACAAJ) in learning the index language of tensoring SU(N) representations, but it is obvious from your comments that this would be runaway overkill, as you just want quark wavefunctions of hadrons, gotten far more directly and, in the case of SU(2), same as in undergraduate QM spin laddering, trivially.  (Your pion example is doubly fraught, since it involves the conjugate rep with upstairs indices, and the funny - sign that attaches to it.)

For spin, recall from elementary QM that adding three spin doublets yields you a spin *j* =3/2 quartet, and two spin *j* =1/2 doublets. The quartet is perfectly symmetric, so its $j_z=3/2$ component is just $|\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \rangle$, which spin-ladders ($J_-$) down to the spin $j_z=1/2$ component,
$$
\psi_{10}=\frac {1}{\sqrt{3}}(|\downarrow \uparrow \uparrow \rangle+|\uparrow \downarrow \uparrow \rangle+|\uparrow \uparrow \downarrow \rangle),
$$
perforce orthogonal to the two spin 1/2 doublets with the *same* spin $j_z=1/2$ components,
$$
\psi_{8}=\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}(-|\downarrow \uparrow \uparrow \rangle+ |\uparrow \uparrow \downarrow \rangle),\qquad 
\psi_{8'}=\frac {1}{\sqrt{6}}(|\downarrow \uparrow \uparrow \rangle-2 |\uparrow \downarrow \uparrow \rangle+|\uparrow \uparrow \downarrow \rangle),
$$
which are also orthogonal to each other, and, naturally, both up-ladder to 0.

Ignore spins now, and reinterpret them as isospin, and the $\psi_{10}$ will give you  the $\Delta$ baryon (in the eightfold way decuplet, in which you might not be interested, by all appearances. You might have to multiply its wave function by a corresponding spin such, and a color-antisymmetrized one, but you also might wish to not look there yet.). So your $\Delta^+$ is but $\frac {1}{\sqrt{3}}(| duu\rangle  +| udu\rangle + | uud\rangle )$. The mixed symmetry isodoublets also combine to put together the mixed symmetry nucleon isodoublet (again, mixed-symmetrize with spin, and fully antisymmetrized by color, in the eightfold way octet).

If that's all you wanted, you are done.

Answer (score 4):

The Young Tableau of the tensor product will tell you the symmetries of the tensors that transform in each representation. Since we don't have access to any Young Tableaux packages I will have to draw them with ASCII.

For example, $2 \otimes 2 = 3 \oplus 1$ looks like
$$▊\otimes▊ = ▊▊ + \cdot,$$
where $\cdot$ means the trivial, one-dimensional rep. The $3$ is represented by $▊▊$ and boxes in the same row represent the process of symmetrising indices and subtracting the trace. This is what OP wrote in their first equation. The trivial rep is the trace, $q^{k}q_{k}$, which OP has written with the invariant $\delta^{i}{}_{j}$.

Let's continue for $2 \otimes 2 \otimes 2 = (3 \oplus 1)\otimes 2 = (3 \otimes 2) \oplus (1 \otimes 2) = [4 \oplus 2] \oplus 2 = 4 \oplus 2 \oplus 2$. In Young Tableux we get
$$▊\otimes ▊ \otimes ▊ = (▊▊ \oplus \cdot)\otimes ▊ = (▊▊\otimes▊)\oplus (▊ \otimes \cdot) = [▊▊▊ \oplus ▊] \oplus ▊ = ▊▊▊ \oplus ▊ \oplus ▊$$
where I have used that 
$$ \begin{matrix}▊ &\!\!\!\!\! ▊ \\ ▊\end{matrix} = ~ ▊$$ because two boxes in the same column are antisymmetrised away (for $SU(N)$ it would be $N$ boxes).

The $4$ representation corresponds to $▊▊▊$ which is fully symmetrised in the three indices and with the trace subtracted.

Does that help you to write down the tensor that transforms in that representation?

Comment: By the way, I'm afraid that I am confused by the fact that you've written your indices upstairs and downstairs for the same representation, $2$...

Comment: That's because the notation is: $2^*$ for upper index $2$ for lower one. As in $SU(2)$ both transform in the same way, it doesn't matter at all. But, i'm trying to keep the notation for $SU(3)$, where the equation posted represents $3\otimes 3^*=8\oplus 1$ and the upper-lower indexes do matter.

Comment: your response helps, but i'm looking for a matrix representation where the quartet is evident.

Comment: OK, yes it's true that for su(2) the distinction is not important. As for your matrix representation my answer contains the information you need to construct it yourself because I tell you the symmetry the tensor will have (fully symmetric and traceless). It's harder to write it as a matrix per se because it will naturally come with three indices - you need the fully symmetric traceless part of the 2x2x2 three-tensor

Comment: For example, a pion triplet is obtained from $T_i^j=q_iq^j=-\frac{1}{2}\delta^j_iq_kq^k$ if $q=\left(u\;d\right)^T$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
T_1^1=u\bar{u}-\frac{1}{2}\left(u\bar u+d\bar d\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\pi^0
\end{equation}
In the same way, $T_2^1=\pi^+$ and so on. We can do a matrix representation:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \pi^- \\ \pi^+ & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I want to do the same thing to obtain a $Delta$-baryon quartet in $SU(2)$ symmetry.

Comment: Do you know a tensor representation for a $SU(2)$ quartet? I think it must have been obtained from some tensor method in $2\otimes 2\otimes 2$ resolution but i couldn't find one.

Comment: i know about the three indexes but i'm thinking in a 3D matrix and if some entries are repeated, maybe we can find an 2D equivalent representation. I mean, a $2\times 2$ matrix have four entries and i´m trying to put them all inside the matrix.

Comment: Your pions naturally fit into a matrix of that form because the come from a single tensor product of fundamental reps and your matrix showcases the same decomposition into irreducible subspaces that the Young Tableaux represent. For the combination of three fundamental reps I repeat that the final result is an object with three indices, a three tensor so it doesn't make sense to write it in two-tensor form